# Is the extra space complexity of a function that counts letter occurrences O(1) for both a hashmap and list implementation?

Tags: python, list, hashmap, big-o, space-complexity

If you use a hashmap (or dict in python) and add a new key /increment key count for every letter found O(n) or O(1)? I ask because the max size of the hashmap will be for 26 keys

the alternative solution is to initialize an array of zeroes of length 26 and increment the index corresponding to a letter if it occurs (increment arr[0] if a exists for example).  from my understanding, such a solution would require O(1) extra space.

I guess the overarching question is if an input can only have x unique character input , then is the extra space considered O(1) ?

Comment: Yes, it is constant space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `N` in `O(N)` is the number of elements in your array. Since your space requirement will be the same whether you pass in 100 elements or 100,000,000, the space requirement is `O(1)`: it doesn't depend on input size.

*Technically*, python integers can grow indefinitely. This means that your space requirement is actually something like `O(log(N))` since `O(log_base_256(N)) = O(log(N) / log(256)) = O(log(N))`. Most other languages have a true `O(1)` requirement because they cap the size of an integer, be it at 32 or 64 bits. For all practical purposes, you can cap the size of an integer at a value large enough to describe all the available memory, and call it `O(1)`.

Comment: so just to clarify, it does't matter if input1 contains 100 occurrences of 'a' or it contains 100 occurrences of every letter (a-z)?  in the case  of input1 the dict would only have one key with value 100, while for input2 it would have 26 keys each with int value 100.  so even though the dictionary is dynamically created , the max number of keys possible is 26 leading to constant extra space?

Comment: @RashanArshad. (1) You can pre-allocate the dictionary (2) big-O notation refers to asymptotic behavior: when input gets large

Comment: point 2 makes sense. for point 1, if you didn't pre-allocate the dictionary, it would be technically more space efficient than pre-allocating or no? which would actually be the most space efficient , dynamically allocated dict, preallocated list , preallocated dict?

Comment: @RashanArshad pre-allocation won't make a difference, in the worst case. I suppose, it could be more efficient not to pre-allocate, in the best case, say, only one letter. And a fully allocated sparse list will be less memory intensive than all but the smallest dicts, but why do you care? The difference at this scale is negligible. The *space complexity* would always be the same, O(1), and practically, very small for both.